# how to use preg_replace & how to enable code if in certain category

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I am looking to add hreflang tags to a product page if it belongs to a certain category id, also I need to edit the output of the string using preg_replace to clean the url for the code.  here is what I have attained so far

```
<?php
foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
    $stores = $group->getStores();
    foreach ($stores as $store) {
        echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $store->getCurrentUrl() . '" hreflang="' . $store->getConfig('general/locale/code') . '"/>' . "\n";
    }
}
}
```

which gives an output of the proper url followed by a ? and extra characters, I need to get rid of those extra characters (.html?5498430jrgfdg30 need to get rid of the ? and everything after it.)  Anyone know how to do this? thanks for all of your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Is your preg replace not working or are you having issues with the language code. Because that part looks good

Comment: oh, whoops My mistake I pasted in the wrong code, that preg_replace actually does not work.  I have edited it.  My question is how to use preg_replace to have it formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Some people, when presented with a problem, choose to quote a crusty old unix bon mot.  Then they have two problems.

Regular expressions are pretty neat, but if there's a well defined parsing router which does exactly what you want, you're better off using it.  PHP's [parse_url](http://www.php.net/parse_url) function is what you want here.

```
$parts = parse_url('http://www.php.net/parse_url?34230948320948&foo=bar');
var_dump($parts);
```

The `$parts` array will contain the URL, separated into parts.  You can then use this information to reconstruct your URL.

Comment: If you have `pecl_http` available, the easiest way to build your new URL is unset the `query` part (from the output of `parse_url`) and then compose the new URL using [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/http_build_query).